# treemodellist: не является членом "ViewshedGeoElement"

Tags: qt, qml, treeview

У меня возникают проблемы, когда я передаю TreeViewModel в qml:

D:\build-ViewshedGeoElement-Desktop_Qt_5_12_2_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug\debug\moc_ViewshedGeoElement.cpp:153: ошибка: C2039: treemodellist: не является членом "ViewshedGeoElement"

По чему так ? Что я не так делаю ?
Мой код :
main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QCommandLineParser>
#include <QDir>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QSurfaceFormat>

#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
#include <Windows.h>
#endif

#include "ViewshedGeoElement.h"
#include "coordinates.h"
#include <QObjectList>
#define STRINGIZE(x) #x
#define QUOTE(x) STRINGIZE(x)
#include <QDirIterator>
#include "treeviewmodel.h"
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QDirIterator it(":/Samples/Analysis/ViewshedGeoElement", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    QString exePath = QFileInfo(argv[0]).absolutePath();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        QString srcFileName = it.next();
        QString dstFileName = exePath + "/../" + QFileInfo(srcFileName).fileName();
        qDebug()<<QDir::currentPath();
        if(!QFile::exists(dstFileName))
            QFile::copy(srcFileName, dstFileName);
    }
qRegisterMetaType<QObjectList>("QObjectList");
qmlRegisterType<TreeViewModel>("ru.host", 1, 0 , "TreeViewModel");
qmlRegisterType<QStandardItemModel>("ru.dom", 1, 0, "QStandardItemModel");

//    qRegisterMetaType<TreeViewModel>("TreeViewModel");
#if defined(Q_OS_LINUX) && !defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)
    // Linux requires 3.2 OpenGL Context
    // in order to instance 3D symbols
    QSurfaceFormat fmt = QSurfaceFormat::defaultFormat();
    fmt.setVersion(3, 2);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(fmt);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.setApplicationName("Viewshed Geoelement- C++");

    // Initialize the sample
    ViewshedGeoElement::init();

    // Initialize application view
    QQuickView view;
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);

    QString arcGISRuntimeImportPath = QUOTE(ARCGIS_RUNTIME_IMPORT_PATH);
    QString arcGISToolkitImportPath = QUOTE(ARCGIS_TOOLKIT_IMPORT_PATH);

#if defined(LINUX_PLATFORM_REPLACEMENT)
    // on some linux platforms the string 'linux' is replaced with 1
    // fix the replacement paths which were created
    QString replaceString = QUOTE(LINUX_PLATFORM_REPLACEMENT);
    arcGISRuntimeImportPath = arcGISRuntimeImportPath.replace(replaceString, "linux", Qt::CaseSensitive);
    arcGISToolkitImportPath = arcGISToolkitImportPath.replace(replaceString, "linux", Qt::CaseSensitive);
#endif

    // Add the import Path
    view.engine()->addImportPath(QDir(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()).filePath("qml"));
    // Add the Runtime and Extras path
    view.engine()->addImportPath(arcGISRuntimeImportPath);
    // Add the Toolkit path
    view.engine()->addImportPath(arcGISToolkitImportPath);

    TreeViewModel treemodellist;
    view.engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("treemodellist",&treemodellist);

    // Set the source
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/Samples/Analysis/ViewshedGeoElement/ViewshedGeoElement.qml"));

    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

ViewshedGeoElement.qml

```
ViewshedGeoElementSample {
   ...
                Rectangle {
                    width: parent.width
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    TreeView {
                        width: parent.width
                        height: parent.height
                        model: treemodellist
                        TableViewColumn {
                            role: "display"
                            title: "Списко 3D моделей"
                            width: 1
                        }
                        itemDelegate: Item {
                            id: listTreeDelegateItem
                            CheckBox {
                                id: checkbox
                                checked:false
                                visible: styleData.value === undefined ? false : true
                                MouseArea {

                                    onClicked: {
                                        if (parent.checked === true) {
                                            parent.checked = false
                                        } else {
                                            parent.checked = true
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            Text {
                                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                                text: styleData.value === undefined ? "" : styleData.value
                                leftPadding : 20
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
...

}
```

treeviewmodel.h

```
#ifndef TREEVIEWMODEL_H
#define TREEVIEWMODEL_H
#include <QStandardItem>

class TreeViewModel: public QStandardItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TreeViewModel(QObject *parent=nullptr);
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(TreeViewModel*)
#endif // TREEVIEWMODEL_H
```

treeviewmodel.cpp

```
#include "treeviewmodel.h"
#include <QStandardItem>
#include "login.h"
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QMessageBox>

TreeViewModel::TreeViewModel(QObject *parent)
    : QStandardItemModel{parent}
{
    setColumnCount(1);
    QStandardItem *rootItem = invisibleRootItem();

    Login conn;
    conn.connOpen();
    QSqlQuery qry(conn.mydb);

    if (qry.exec("SELECT id,name,url FROM \"models\""))
    {
        while(qry.next())
        {
            QStandardItem *value = new QStandardItem;
            value->setText(qry.value(1).toString());
            rootItem->appendRow(value);
            qDebug()<<qry.value(0).toString();
            qDebug()<<qry.value(1).toString();
            qDebug()<<qry.value(2).toString();
        }
    } else {
        qDebug()<<qry.lastError().text();
    }

}
```

ViewshedGeoElement.h

class ViewshedGeoElement : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
...
    Q_PROPERTY(TreeViewModel treemodellist READ treemodellist NOTIFY treemodellistChanged)
...
private:
 TreeViewModel treemodellist;
...
}

ViewshedGeoElement.cpp

...
void ViewshedGeoElement::componentComplete()
{
...
emit treemodellistChanged();

}
...

Comment: Вы пытаетесь класс TreeViewModel передать в qml?

Comment: @Alexander Chernin Да . Может надо зарегистрировать тип TreeViewModel  ?

Comment: Да, вот так `qmlRegisterType<TreeViewModel>("ru.host", 1, 0 , "TreeViewModel");`

Comment: @Alexander Chernin  "Could not convert argument 2 at"
  "expression for index@file:///C:/Qt/Qt5.12.2/5.12.2/msvc2017_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Private/TreeViewItemDelegateLoader.qml:84"
  "insertColumn@file:///C:/Qt/Qt5.12.2/5.12.2/msvc2017_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Private/BasicTableView.qml:262"
  "addColumn@file:///C:/Qt/Qt5.12.2/5.12.2/msvc2017_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Private/BasicTableView.qml:236"
  "expression for onCompleted@file:///C:/Qt/Qt5.12.2/5.12.2/msvc2017_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Private/BasicTableView.qml:358"

Comment: @Alexander Chernin  Остаются ошибки

Comment: Все кастомные типы, которые подтягивает ваш кастомный класс модели дерева должны быть зарегистрированы подобным образом, иначе как интепретатор qml их разберет?

Comment: Покажите ваш main.cpp  целиком

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91400/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-alexander-chernin).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91401/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-alexander-chernin).